# nested http calls in angular2 rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs, observable

I'm new to angular 2 and would like to make nested http calls where one call is dependent on the next call. My code is as follows in service:

```
getUserPosts(): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.apiUserURL + this.userId + '/')
        .map((response: Response)  => response.json())  
        .flatMap((users) => {
            return Observable.forkJoin(
                users.map(user=>
                    this.http.get(this.apiUserPostURL + user.id)
                    .flatMap(response => response.json())   
                )   
            )
        })
}
```

in Components I have:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.results = this.postsService.getUserPosts()
  .subscribe(posts => {  this.posts = posts
    console.log(posts);
  })   
}
```

when I do that I get the last post of every user but not all posts. (I have 3 posts for every user, and I have two users in my database, but below I get only one post of every user:

```
(2) [Object, Object]
0:Object
1:Object
```

**solution expected: get all posts from all users like this:**

```
(6) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

when I change the last part of my service to the following:

```
users.map(user=>
    this.http.get(this.apiUserPostURL + user.id)
    .map(response => response.json())   
)
```

I get two arrays of 3 posts each and I don't know how to access those posts with *ngFor:

```
(2) [Array(3), Array(3)]
0:Array(3)
  0:Object
  1:Object
  2:Object
1:Array(3)
  0:Object
  1:Object
  2:Object
```

**Solution expected: reach out directly to the arrays without having one array of objects for every user but instead one array containing all objects:**

```
(6) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I even tried to do something else which I thought will help by adding .flatMap to my component as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.results = this.postsService.getUserPosts()
 .flatMap(posts => this.posts = posts)
  .subscribe(posts => {  this.posts = posts
    console.log(posts);
  })    
}
```

but I got two separate arrays, each array is related to each user with all his posts, *ngFor only picks the latest user and ignore the other posts from the other user:

```
(3) [Object, Object, Object]
   0: Object
   1: Object
   2: Object
(3) [Object, Object, Object]
   0: Object
   1: Object
   2: Object
```

**Solution expected: merge both arrays into one array as:**

```
(6) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Can anyone please help in figuring out how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to use map instead of flatMap here:  this.http.get(this.apiUserPostURL + user.id) .map(response => response.json())

Comment: @Julia Passynkova   i did that on my second part of my post above and i don't get the desired solution. Any other suggestion?

Comment: use .flatMap((users) => {...]).map(x=> [].concat.apply([],x))

Comment: @Julia Passynkova You are genius. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Julia Passynkova for her answer to allow to solve my problem. this the final solution by adding the last line of concat.apply() to my service:

```
getUserPosts(): Observable<any[]>{
return this.http.get(this.apiUserURL + this.userId + '/')
    .map((response: Response)  => response.json())  
    .flatMap((users) => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
            users.map(user=>
                this.http.get(this.apiUserPostURL + user.id)
                .flatMap(response => response.json())   
            )   
        )
    }).map(x=> [].concat.apply([],x))
```

}